# make gcc pass the arguments by register

Tags: c, linux, gcc

On my 32bit x86 Ubuntu11.10, gcc4.6.3 pass the arguments by stack. Is there any gcc optimization that force gcc to pass arguments by registers? And how gcc do that? I want some details, please.

Comment: [Calling conventions 
for different C++ compilers and operating systems](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant attribute is `__attribute__((fastcall))`. Functions declared with this attribute are called with their first eligible argument in ECX and the second in EDX.

(I'm assuming x86. You just said 32 bits, but that covers many architectures such as ARM).

Comment: Only two registers can be used?

Comment: @KUN: It's x86. It doesn't have that many registers to start with.

Comment: Do you know any gcc optimization can do it just like on x86-64?

Comment: @KUN: Obviously not. x86-64 uses RCX/RDX instead of ECX/EDX (64 bits), and adds R8 and R9. x86 doesn't have an R8 or R9 register.

Answer (score 3):

GCC passes arguments on stack in your case because the Linux-x86 ABI specifies that. With the fastcall function attribute you can change that, which of course breaks the ABI and causes all kinds of problems due to that.

A solution could be to swith to x86-64, where the ABI specifies that (some) arguments are passed by registers. Or if you like bleeding edge stuff, the newish x32 ABI is similar to the x86-64 ABI but with 32-bit pointers.

Comment: I know x86-64 ABI can do that. Since I just have the 32bit machine, want to find out whether gcc optimization can do that or not.